# Replace substring with nothing

Tags: r, regex

How can I replace everything starting with the _ with just nothing?

Here is a simple data frame

```
d <- data.frame(a = c("A_foo1", "B_foo2", " _foo3"))
```

I want d to look like:

```
a
A
B
" "
```

Comment: Did you try anything? This is very easy to do with `gsub`...

Comment: I dont know gsub. I am trying replace, grep and substr at the moment. Will look into gsub now

Comment: `?grep` should give you information into a vareity of string/regex commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
a <- c("A_foo1", "B_foo2", " _foo3")
gsub("_.*", "", a)
#[1] "A" "B" " "
```

Comment: If you have some additional complexity in your strings you can be even more explicit and use the grouping features of regexes:  `gsub('^(.*)_.*$', '\\1', a)`

Comment: Can you think of a case where the output would be different?  The regular expressions are greedy by default which is why I went with the answer I did.

Comment: Not really, that's why I deleted my answer.  I just like to be as explicit as possible and work backwards rather than the other way around once I notice behavior I didn't expect.