# Replace character on string with nothing in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a vector of strings and I'd like to remove the 5th character of each element of the vector. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570312/replace-substring-with-nothing), but it's not very helpful to me.

At first, I thought that

```
substr(myvec, 5,5) <- ""
```

would do the trick. But it happened that this code doesn't work.

A workaround to do what I intend to do is just:

```
paste(substr(myvec, 1,4), substr(myvec, 6,nchar(myvec)), sep="")
```

But is it really impossible to use substr directly, as I intended to do?
Below is a reproducible example.

```
myvec <- c("19601Urbana", "19601Rural", "19701Urbana", "19701Rural", "19801Urbana", "19801Rural", "19912Urbana", "19912Rural", "20002Urbana", "20002Rural", "20102Urbana", "20102Rural")
```

Any ideas? I guess I could try some regex, but It seems that it will be a little bit hard to use it. Also, it seems overkill.

update: Since some people say it works on their computer, my session info:
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
I'm using windows 8.

Comment: `substr(myvec, 5,5) <- ""` *does* work

Comment: @rawr Really? I tried it and it does not work for me. You can set `substr(myvec,5,5) <- "a"` for example, but not to the empty string.

Comment: I just ran `x<-"aaaaXaa"; x; substr(x,5,5)<-""; x` in "R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)" and it removed the "X".

Comment: When I run `z<-"aaaaXaaa";substr(z,5,5)<-"";z` I get: `[1] "aaaaXaaa"`. `R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: `substr(myvec, 5,5) <- "" ` does not work for me either, but anything else works, e.g. setting it equal to `" "`, or `"a"`, etc. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Works for me on ubuntu 12.04, R3.1.1. This regex (i think) will delete the number immediately before the start of the text `gsub("(.*)\\d(.*)", "\\1\\2", myvec)` (although its sore on the eyes ;))

Comment: Based on comment and my updated question (with my session info), it seems that it works on Ubuntu and Mac, but not Windows. Maybe it's something related to being Unix based vs not? Or maybe encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the comments, I get the same result you do. For whatever reason, setting `substr(...)` to the empty string does nothing (on my system). So here's a workaround.

```
ch <- intToUtf8(1)          # non-printing character
substr(myvec,5,5) <- ch     # substitute that
gsub(ch,"",myvec,fixed=T)   # now get rid of it...
#  [1] "1960Urbana" "1960Rural"  "1970Urbana" "1970Rural"  "1980Urbana" ...
```

And yes, it's a pita.